# R - Controlling interaction order in model matrix

Tags: r, interaction, model.matrix

I would like to control the order of interaction dummy codes in a design matrix, separately from the order of main effects dummy codes. Specifically the order in which the terms that make the interaction are cycled through.

For example:

```r
df <- expand.grid(X1 = letters[1:3],
                  X2 = LETTERS[24:26])
```

When writing the formula as `~X1+X2+X1:X2`, the interaction design cycles through `X2` and then through `X1`.

```r
model.matrix(~X1+X2+X1:X2, df)
#>   (Intercept) X1b X1c X2Y X2Z X1b:X2Y X1c:X2Y X1b:X2Z X1c:X2Z
#> 1           1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 2           1   1   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 3           1   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 4           1   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0
#> 5           1   1   0   1   0       1       0       0       0
#> 6           1   0   1   1   0       0       1       0       0
#> 7           1   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0
#> 8           1   1   0   0   1       0       0       1       0
#> 9           1   0   1   0   1       0       0       0       1
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$X1
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
#> 
#> attr(,"contrasts")$X2
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
```

When I flip the interaction term in the formula to `~X1+X2+X2:X1`, the interaction design still cycles first through `X2` and then through `X1`.

```r
model.matrix(~X1+X2+X2:X1, df)
#>   (Intercept) X1b X1c X2Y X2Z X1b:X2Y X1c:X2Y X1b:X2Z X1c:X2Z
#> 1           1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 2           1   1   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 3           1   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 4           1   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0
#> 5           1   1   0   1   0       1       0       0       0
#> 6           1   0   1   1   0       0       1       0       0
#> 7           1   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0
#> 8           1   1   0   0   1       0       0       1       0
#> 9           1   0   1   0   1       0       0       0       1
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$X1
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
#> 
#> attr(,"contrasts")$X2
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
```

What I would like end up with is the following design matrix:

```r
#>   (Intercept) X1b X1c X2Y X2Z X1b:X2Y X1b:X2Z X1c:X2Y X1c:X2Z
#> 1           1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 2           1   1   0   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 3           1   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       0
#> 4           1   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0
#> 5           1   1   0   1   0       1       0       0       0
#> 6           1   0   1   1   0       0       0       1       0
#> 7           1   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0
#> 8           1   1   0   0   1       0       1       0       0
#> 9           1   0   1   0   1       0       0       0       1
```

Thanks!